# Adding iddentifiable non-field errors

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I am doing some custom validation in the `clean` method in a `ModelForm`. I want to add custom non-field error messages, but I need them to be identifiable by some kind of key, so this doesn't work:

```
self.add_error(None, 'Custom error message 1')
self.add_error(None, 'Custom error message 2')
self.add_error(None, 'Custom error message 3')
```

I need to be able to tell these apart to render them in an appropriate place in the invalid form template instead of having them all grouped as `None` non-field errors.

How can I do that?

Comment: @Fomalhaut did you even read my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ValidationError` class, which supports a `code` parameter in its initialiser. Then instead of getting the strings for the `non_field_errors()`, fetch the actual `data`:

```
self.add_error('__all__', ValidationError("Custom error message", code="type1")
...
for error in self.non_field_errors().data:  # non_field_errors() returns an ErrorList instance
     print(error.code)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard way in django for doing that. But you can implement your own little method if you really want that.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def add_non_field_error(self, group, error):
        errors = self._errors.setdefault(group, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
        errors.append(error)


f = MyForm(data={})
f.is_valid()  # True
f.add_non_field_error('no_field', 'This is an error.')
f.is_valid()  # False
f.errors  # {'no_field': ['This is an error.']}
```